# UWP DataContractSerializer ReadObject throws System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, uwp, datacontractserializer

I have tested it even on empty classes. Serialization is going fine, but when I call ReadObject method, it thorws System.TypeInitializationException. Details:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator' threw an
>   exception.'

Inner Exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The API
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(System.Type)'
>   cannot be used on the current platform. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.

I searched for it on SO and whole Google, but no success.

Target of project: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices' relevant APIs are the new features which are introduced from .NET Standard 2.0. Please check the [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices)

In order to use .NET Standard 2.0 in UWP, you need to target Fall Creators Update (FCU) as the minimum version of your UWP project. Please read [Announcing UWP Support for .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/) for more information.